# One Task Two Docker Containers, do I have to use SRV or A DNS Record Type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have one task in AWS which contains two docker containers. One container is a small server that is running and second one is somewhat of a side cart. Docker container A exposes port 80 and container B exposes port 8080. Any communication between the two is done via localhost since I am using `awsvpc` mode.

I now have container C which needs to talk to Container A. I am trying to use 'Service Discovery' for this. What I'm confused about is once I have my `Service Discovery` configured using `A` type DNS record, how would the `Service Discovery` know to use port `80`? This makes me think I need to use `SRV` DNS record type which allows me to specify the port. Which DNS record type should I be using?

Comment: Why not use `localhost` for container C to talk to container A? If all the containers are in the same task you shouldn't need service discovery.

Comment: Container C is running on another Ecs service and a different task

Comment: You would probably need to use SRV records then. But you would probably have to write code to query the SRV records and create your network connections from the response. You can't just issue HTTP requests against endpoints defined in SRV records.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that by default querying <service-discovery-name>.<namespace-name> automatically goes to port 443. If I define port 443, on one of the containers shouldn’t that just route the request to that container?

Comment: The fact you are using `https://` is what is making it automatically go to port `443`. Because that is the default port for the HTTPS protocol. If the port never changes across your containers then you could just use `A` records and hard-code the port in your code. It's unclear if your ports ever change because you haven't specified if you are even using ECS or EKS or some other AWS container solution, and you haven't mentioned if you are deploying to EC2 or Fargate execution environments, or the networking mode you are using for the containers.

Comment: My bad. ECS Fargate. In such case would I need to specify the port number with my request then? The container is listening on port 80 by default. I’ve exposed port 80 and 443.

Comment: On Fargate the port should always be the same, so you should be able to use `A` records and just specify `http://` or `https://` to use the default ports `80` and `443` respectively.

Comment: That’s what I’m doing. Not sure why the connection keeps getting rejected then. The network logs specify the source container it’s up address and mention ingress connection rejected. A bit confused. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Do the security group rules allow the traffic?